# How to convert sampling sampling variances for a meta-analysis using raw means as effect sizes?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I am conducting a meta-analysis using raw mean scores as effect sizes (i.e., reported test scores on a certain standardized test).

I found a calculation formula for sampling variances provided by, e.g., Card (2012, p. 150), Hox (2010, p. 209), and also [[Calculation for the estimated sampling variance of individual group raw mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207426/calculation-for-the-estimated-sampling-variance-of-individual-group-raw-mean]).

> SEx = Sx/√N

- where `s` is the standard deviation of variable `X`, and `N` is the sample size.

Especially, Card's book, `Applied Meta-analysis for social science research` was very helpful providing an equation for transforming scores between two different scales.

> Card (2012, p. 148)
>
> X2 = ((X1 - Min1)((Max2 - Min2)/(Max1 - Min1))+Min2
>
> - where, X2 is the equivalent score on the second scale
> - X1 is the score on the first scale that you wish to transform.
> - Min1 is the lowest possible score on the first scale.
> - Max1 is the highest possible score on the first scale.
> - Min2 is the lowest possible score on the second scale.
> - Max2 is the highest possible score on the second scale.

However, the book does not provide how to calculate sampling variances when ESs were transformed into a standardized value.

I would really appreciate it if you could let me know how sampling variances could be calculated for this standardized effect size. If possible, references that I can cite would be much appreciated.

Comment: SE(X2) = SE(X1)(Max2 - Min2)/(Max1 - Min1)

Comment: Thank you for your response, @user158565! Could you let me know how you find the formula? I am wondering if you know any reference that I can cite. Thank you in advance!