# Meta-analysis of studies with single group having pre-test and post-test mean

Tags: meta-analysis, metafor

I am trying to do a meta-analysis using studies with single group (in my case- patients undergoing an XYZ surgery). The outcome measures reported are pre-treat functional score(mean with SD) and Post-treat functional score ((mean with SD). Complications are reported as rates.
I am relatively new to meta-analysis, so can anyone suggest some options on how to proceed?
My aim is to :

1. pool the pre-treat and post-treat functional scores.
   2)pool the complication rates
2. try to see if the change in the pooled pre-treat and post-treat functional score are statistically significant.

Thank you.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: I think from your description that you need to compute a measure of change for each study and then pool those.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. Can you please guide me how to compute measure of change and then pool the data?

Comment: Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422478/pooled-analysis-of-studies-with-only-intervention-arm?rq=1 help?

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't understand it.